# When app data is cleared from settings shared preferences gets blank in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

When i clear an app data from settings my shared preferences value gets lost. but this should not happen. As i want to save these value as long as app in installed on the device.
Please suggest some alternatives for this or some solution.

Please help......

Answer (score 0):

For your need you might have to store the data in some file in the external storage and store and pick the data from the file instead of shared preference.

You may want to refer to the link

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html